# coldfusion cfquery.getMetaData()

Tags: coldfusion, cfquery

I have a simple cfquery object:

```
<cfquery name="getP" datasource="DS">
   select top 5 * from table
</cfquery>
```

When I do a dump of `getP.getMetaData()`, I clearly see **`getPrecision(int)`** in the method list. Though, when I perform **`getP.getMetaData().getPrecision(1)`**, I get an error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: getPrecision()
```

***What am I doing wrong?***

The error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javadocs say it's not supported yet, hence it throws that error.

http://sqlitejdbc.sourceforge.jp/org/sqlite/jdbc/JdbcParameterMetaData.html

Comment: Hence the `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` error it throws, as per the documentation